# Программы для спеллчекинга больших текстов

Tags: linux, поиск-программ

Ищу бесплатные оффлайн GUI программы для спеллчекинга больших текстов (от нескольких тысяч слов) с возможностью игнорировать определённые слова. Нужен хотя бы английский язык. Нужен хотя бы простейший поиск по словарю без замен.

`aspell`, `hunspell` и прочие CMD-утилиты не подходят из-за сложности настройки для нормального использования (необходимо готовить файлы, копировать куда-то результаты, исключения задаются тоже ручками). Нужен простой GUI, в который можно скопипастить текст, а он покажет список ошибок, а по клику можно заигнорировать ненужные слова.

Пока что нашёл только `languagetool`, но он работает очень медленно для больших текстов. Но самое главное, что нельзя делать исключения для конкретных слов, а только отключать правило полностью.

Comment: Microsoft office word :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков добавил тег для линукса, прошу прощения

Comment: Microsoft office word под wine xD

Comment: Любой офисный пакет. Почтовые клиенты.